# UIImage Scale according to User Distance from Wall (AR)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, augmented-reality

I'm developing an iOS app based on augmented reality. What it suppose to do is user will set his distance from wall. Then he'll select a picture from gallery and see how will it look on the wall. App should scale the UIImage accordingly to the distance of user from wall and user can drag it to see how it look on the wall.
 What I was able to do till now is to access the camera so that the wall can be viewed. And to insert an overlay picture on it that a user can drag in the View.
What I'm unable to do is how to scale it accordingly to the distance. What's the formula to calculate this?
Example: I'm standing 2 meters away from the wall and the image is 4x3 Feet. It should scale the image if I select that now I'm 3 feet away.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved using an augmented reality library such as [vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/ios)

you would need a printed target image to hold against the wall though, and the picture can be displayed on the wall correctly overlaying the target image. the library can tell how far away it is by the size of the target image

Comment: Is there any other or local library? Because with printed target is something I don't want to do! I've seen that example in the video on vuforia website. But in my case its a wall so someone should hold the printed target which is no good!

Comment: well they could stick it to the wall heh, but unfortunately i dont think i have an answer for your problem

Answer (score 0):

why not let the user resize the image once it is overlaid on the wall? 
Of course Fonix's idea is one solution.

Another solution I'm thinking of is to use GPS. You should know the GPS location of the wall and you can get the GPS location of the device. Then you compute the distance between the two GPS locations and based on the computed distance you resize the image. You will also have to consider the orientation of the device in order to detect whether the device's camera points to the wall.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. but what I'm doing now is to let user set his distance from wall through a UISlider i.e. 1 to 6 meters and the picture displays accordingly.